# Ack "unmatched ( in regex" error

Tags: regex, ack

I am really confused by this:

I am trying to `ack` for all calls to a JavaScript function `hideSideBar(arg1, arg2, etc..)` in my project.

Because it can optionally be called with no arguments, I started by just looking for instances of `hideSideBar(`

```
ack hideSideBar\(
error: Unmatched ( in regex ...
```

I am very confused, because I am escaping the left-paren... so why is it looking for a closing parenthesis?

(I am aware I could use a wildcard and do `ack hideSideBar\(.*\)` to get what I'm looking for.  I'm more interested in understanding why what I attempted to do doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting `hideSidebar\(` in quotes with and without the backslash?

Comment: Wow. Well, that fixed it.  Why does it need surrounding "'s to make it work?

Comment: The shell will interpret the backslash before `ack` sees it, adding the quotes tells the shell to leave it alone. Sorry for the all edits on this comment, I was having a bit of a "leave the damn backslash alone" problem myself :)

Comment: If someone wants to give an answer I'll mark it as correct... :-)   Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `ack hideSideBar\(` in the terminal,
the shell will remove the `\` and pass `hideSideBar(` to `ack`.

So `hideSideBar\(` should be enclosed in `'...'`(or `"..."`),
the shell will remove the quotes and pass `hideSideBar\(` to `ack`.